# How do I replace a string with values from a dictionary? Python

Tags: python

My code...

```
sentence = "hello world helloworld"

dictionary = {"hello": "1", "world": "2", "helloworld": "3"}

for key in dictionary:
    sentence = sentence.replace(key, dictionary[key])

print(sentence)
```

What I want it to do...

```
1 2 3
```

What it actually does...

```
1 2 12
```

Comment: Please specify, if your `sentence` only contains words from the dictionary, or if other words are possible. Also in the current form you will get an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Comment: My sentence will only contain words from the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sentence = "hello world helloworld"
sentence = sentence.split()

dictionary = {"hello": "1", "world": "2", "helloworld": "3"}

print ' '.join(map(lambda x: dictionary.get(x) or x , sentence))
```

Comment: This works if any possible word in `sentence` actually exists in the dictionary.

Comment: Really like the or-approach. +1

Comment: `dict.get(x) or x` could be made slightly shorter using the default argument: `dict.get(x, x)`

Comment: @HannesOvrén, I do agree that it is shorter, but it's confusing at the same time, right?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not convinced it is necessarily better.

Answer (score 1):

If your sentence can contain words not in your dictionary, which should be returned unchanged, try this approach:

```
sentence = "hello world helloworld missing words"
sentence = sentence.split()

dictionary = {"hello": "1", "world": "2", "helloworld": "3"}

for i, word in enumerate(sentence):
    sentence[i] = dictionary[word] if word in dictionary else word

print(" ".join(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the replacements is important. In your case:

- when `hello` is replaced      :  "1 world 1world"
- when `world` is first replace :  "1 2 12"

To avoid it iterate the keys by order of their length. from the longest to shorter.

```
for key in dictionary.keys().sort( lambda aa,bb: len(aa) - len(bb) ):
    sentence = sentence.replace(key, dictionary[key])
```